# Neo4j: bad result using the WITH statement

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

To import a json into Neo4J, I use these two requests:

Request 1:

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:///files.json") yield value
unwind value.nodes as node
merge (file:File {id:node.path}) ON CREATE SET file.name = node.name
```

Request 2:

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:///files.json") yield value
unwind value.edges as edge
MATCH
    (source:File {id: edge.sourceId}),
    (target:File {id: edge.targetId})
CREATE (source)-[:`R`]->(target)
```

The result is the correct one (254 nodes and 3578 relationships).

Now I will like to merge these two queries into one, so I am using the WITH statement as follows:

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:///files.json") yield value
unwind value.nodes as node
merge (file:File {id:node.path}) ON CREATE SET file.name = node.name
WITH value
unwind value.edges as edge
MATCH
    (source:File {id: edge.sourceId}),
    (target:File {id: edge.targetId})
CREATE (source)-[:`R`]->(target)
```

I get the right number of nodes but not the right number of edges (254 nodes and 908812 relationships).
Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand the problem, but found a solution by replacing the MATCH / CREATE part of the relationship.

Valid request:

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:///files.json") yield value
unwind value.nodes as node
merge (file:File {id:node.path}) ON CREATE SET file.name = node.name
WITH value
unwind value.edges as edge
MATCH (source:File {id: edge.sourceId}), (target:File {id: edge.targetId})
MERGE (source)-[:`R`]->(target)
```

Comment: that was actually the problem, you were always creating new edges in the initial query.